# difference between contents of two directories

Tags: linux

I have find the difference in all the cpp, header and shell scripts files between
two directories which can have subdirectories as well.

Comment: What do you mean? You can use any diff tool, e.g. diff or meld

Comment: @Mine OP may simply not know those tools. You should make an answer based on diff.

Comment: @dystroy Sorry, but I didn't know what the question is about... I just guess the question is about how to do diff two directories.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the recursive option of diff

```
diff -r old_dir new_dir
```

Comment: it shows all the files even .o files i want specific filter such as .cpp i tried <diff -r old_dir new_dir | grep ".cpp"> if there is folder named cpp in the path then that is also displayed

Comment: you can use --exclude to filter out the undesired files